# Someone keeps sending me a link via bluetooth - how to stop them without disabling bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, finder, bluetooth, privacy, url

In my Macbook, I keep getting a popup about a website link sent from an iPhone:

[image]

I didn't even know about that feature, but anyway - the link is some random chinese website every time. Whenever I open it, the popup appears again as if there is some sort of long queue of the same link.

If I disable bluetooth, the popup stops. But as soon as I enable it back, the stream continues.

When I got to the advanced Bluetooth settings, there doesn't seem to be an option to block this kind of thing. The only device that shows up are my BeatsX.

How can I stop this, without having to turn off bluetooth?

I am using macOS High Sierra, 10.13.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [**Handoff**](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25169), part of [Continuity](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25131), where **devices signed into the same primary iCloud account** can ‘hand off’ currently viewed content between each other.

Handoff isn't available for anyone to share content with you — this is only for you to share content between your own devices. I would be very concerned that someone has access to my iCloud account on a supposedly unknown device. I recommend investigating this further if you are unaware of the Continuity source.

You can disable all Continuity features including Handoff in System Preferences → General → Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices.

[image]